# Google Maps Android API: Map style parsing failed: null when setting map style

Tags: android

I've added a custom map style json file to my app project and it's been working fine for about a year. However, I recently noticed that it suddenly stopped working. It works fine in the emulator with the debug and release build, but when installing the app from Google Play, loading the custom map style fails.

Logcat says:

```
E Google Maps Android API: Map style parsing failed: null
```

Here's the relevant code.

```
int mapStyle = getMapStyle(prefs);
googleMap.setMapStyle(
    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(context, R.raw.mapstyle_winter));
```

Using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0`